# How to do a right click detection command

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to make it so when you right click an iron ingot it gives you a diamond and I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Except when I go on there, the video in the comments does not work

Comment: The video in the answer is indeed deleted, that's the reason why people shouldn't rely on external websites for their answers. But there are two more links in the comment. And the answer already has the necessary concept, the commands can be figured out using the wiki. Or, since right click detection is a common thing, just google "right click detection minecraft 1.13".

Comment: I do seach it up and everything I see doesnt work at all

Comment: Then ask about those problems instead of your overall project.

Comment: I am............

Comment: I don't know what else to tell you now other than 1. google it, 2. be more specific.

Comment: First, Searched it up, didnt work because what other people do is trash, second I did be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

i don't Think you can do it in vanilla minecraft you will need some plugins

if you are trying to do it on vanilla minecraft so i don't Think there is a way or if there is i don't know it
but if you are using plugins you can use itemizer or ItemEdit to add a lore of /give @p minecraft:diamond 1

Comment: (not being mean) First, what plugins? and if you do a lore of /give it wouldnt work

Comment: it depends on what plugin you're  using some plugin support the / at start of lores to set is at a detection commands and some plugins needs Another own command to set a detection commands
as CYOM support it where you can just add a lore of /give and it will do the command /give but with Essentials plugin you can just add a lore with / at the start to work

if you was using CYOM you'll need to do the normal lore command /menu script add (lore you want or slash a start for a command)

if youre using essentiaals you will need to do /pt (command) to add a command to the item you're holding